# Spacing Between a letters

Tags: vba, catia

I have a text creation macro with me for CATIA V5
I want to include spacing between the letters for the text created in drafting
What is the best possible way for that

Comment: Can you show an example of the current text value, and the target/desired output text?

Answer (score 1):

For spacing of texts on drawing use following method:

```
MyDrawingText.SetParameterOnsubString catCharSpacing,0,0,25
```

You can find it in the catia help file *V5Automation.chm* in the catia installation sub-folder:

> \win_b64\code\bin\

in the *V5Automation.chm* search for *DrawingText*.